# MySQL subquery with LIMIT alternative

Tags: mysql, sql

What I want:

```
SELECT u.username, u.last_activity 
FROM users_userprofile 
WHERE u.id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT(p.user_id) FROM forums_post p 
    WHERE p.thread_id = 423993 
    ORDER BY p.created_at DESC 
    LIMIT 4
);
```

This doesn't work because of `LIMIT` in subquery. I want to keep order of subquery but I want to get `username` and `last_activity` instead of `user_id`.

Any suggestion how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the subquery with a view:

```
CREATE VIEW subv AS     SELECT p.user_id FROM forums_post p 
WHERE p.thread_id = 423993 
ORDER BY p.created_at DESC 
LIMIT 4;

SELECT u.username, u.last_activity 
FROM users_userprofile 
WHERE u.id IN (SELECT * FROM subv);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why woldn't you do it with a `JOIN`? There seems to be no performance impact because `WHERE` and `LIMIT` clauses are the same. It won't `JOIN` the whole tables:

```
SELECT p.user_id, u.username, u.last_activity 
FROM users_userprofile u
JOIN forums_post p ON p.user_id = u.id
WHERE p.thread_id = 423993 
GROUP BY p.user_id ORDER BY MAX(p.created_at) DESC 
LIMIT 4
```

Comment: Sry, I forgot DISTINCT(p.user_id) in my original question.

Comment: @Spindel, updated the code. It should work with DISTINCT too.

Comment: This was actually the first query I tried but unfortunately it doesn't ORDER BY p.created (it looks like random order).

Comment: @Spindel, maybe replace `DISTINCT` with `GROUP BY p.user_id ORDER BY MAX(p.created_at)` to choose only last posts. It seems to work with sample data. Please take a look at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dfe2d/1/0

Answer (score 0):

you could use `join` for the table and the subquery instead of using `where in`:

```
SELECT u.username, u.last_activity 
FROM users_userprofile u
JOIN (
       SELECT p.user_id FROM forums_post p 
       WHERE p.thread_id = 423993 
       ORDER BY p.created_at DESC 
       LIMIT 4
     ) q
on u.user_id=q.user_id
```

Comment: Sry, I forgot DISTINCT(p.user_id) in my original question.